# Create boundingBox for shapes in java - use to select, drag and drop, rotate, translate

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to create a bounding box in order to select a shape. I have a vector of shapes and a vector of all the points. The objective is to put some shape inside a bounding box, and then I can apply some transformations like move some shape around the canvas, rotate, resize etc.

Now I'm focus on the bounding box to select and move some shape. The other transformations are for later.

**Here is the class, and I know that at least, I need this variables**

```
public class BoundingBox {

int xmax;
int xmin;
int ymax;
int ymin;

public BoundingBox(Vector<Point> points) {

}
```

**I have other classes implemented, for example, I have a editor panel with this**

```
Vector<Shape> shapes;
// Current shape that is in construction (if any)
Shape currentShape;
// shape that is selected, if any
Shape selectedShape;
```

**A class that implements a shape**

```
protected Vector<Point> points;
protected boolean isAShapeBeingBuilt;   //is any shape being built?
protected boolean selected;             //is any shape selected?
protected ShapesEditorPanel parent;     // reference to the panel
```

I can´t put all the code here, obviously, but I hope that with this information some can help me. The main problem is how to select and move some shape inside a box!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The `Shape` class already supports a `getBounds()` method to get the bounding `Rectangle` of the Shape.

Comment: My shape class? Or are you refering to shape class of java?

Comment: The `Shape` class of Java. The point to my answer was you should be using the Shape class of Java. It already provides the functionality you need.

Comment: Yes, but I cant use that class. In this work is supposed to do all that stuff "by hand" :D

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, do not use Vector, as your code is running on a single thread. Use ArrayList instead.

Then, if you want to find the bounding box, you need to create a rectangle for which the diagonal is defined by the point(smallestX, smallestY) and the point(biggestX, biggestY). Iterate through your shape's point to find minimum and maximums for x and y coordinates.

Comment: I'm using vector because some code was given by teacher... Is not to be modified, but thanks for the advice.

What you mean by diagonal? I was thinking of a rectangle that the edges passes by the points that you said. Is that what you meant?

Comment: A rectangle can be defined only by its big diagonal, which is the line that either goes from its lowest left corner to its highest right corner, or from its lowest right corner to its highest left corner. Alternatively, you can define four points and create the rectangle from them. However, you would need to validate that the four points indeed make a rectangle.

Comment: But is that a java method to create a rectangle?

Comment: I've checked, and no. Java's rectangle requires the top left corner's point, a height and a width.

Comment: Ok, thank for the help. And with de select, move and transform issue, what you advise?

Comment: Depends for each transformation. I'd make a Transformation interface, and start from there.